# Does Imagenet contain unlabeled data?

Tags: unsupervised-learning, imagenet

Does Imagenet contain unlabeled examples like [STL-10](https://ai.stanford.edu/%7Eacoates/stl10/) dataset? because I see that the dataset is used for unsupervised learning but it seems to me it has only labeled examples.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help]

Comment: Beyond the fact that this is not a programming question, as the answer below correctly points out, you don't *need* unlabeled data in order to try unsupervised algorithms - you just do not use the labels provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the ImageNet data using ImageFolder in Pytorch. For unsupervised learning, simply don't account for the labels coming from the Dataloader